# Switch between 2 queries basing on a parameter passed

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two different queries

1. Domain
2. Project Managers

Domain query output:

| Name | emailid | overallProjects_count | Overallprojects_Greencount | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A@xxx.com | 24 | 22 | domainhead |
| C | C@xxx.com | 40 | 39 | domainhead |

Project Managers query output:

| Name | emailid | project_name | phase | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | B@xxx.com | SQCM | Development | Projectmanager |
| D | D@xxx.com | Remedydashboards | UAT | projectmanager |

I need to pass email ID's or names to find out if he is Domain or Project Manager and then run either 1st query or 2nd query.

EG: 3rd query table:

| Name | EMAILID | Domain/PM (derived field) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A@xxx.com | Domain head |
| B | B@xxx.com | PM |

If I run the third query where EMAILID = B.@xxx.com and got the result that he is a PM, then I need to get the results from 2nd query only.

Since the column structure is different, I tried this approach:

```
SELECT 
    name, emailid, overallprojectscount, overallprojectsgreencount, type, 
    'not for domain heads' as project name, 
    'not for domain heads' as phase
UNION
SELECT 
    name, emailid,
    'not for project manager' AS overallprojectscount,
    'not for project manager' AS overallprojectsgreencount, type, 
    project name, 'not for project manager' AS phase 
WHERE
    emailid = <pass any>
```

This way it will provide all the columns showing "not for domain head' for some and "not for project manager' for some.

Looking for a way wherein rather than doing union, can just run any one query basing on type.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select *
from (select * replace('Domain head' as type) from domain) 
full outer join (select * replace('PM' as type) from project_managers)
using(name, emailid, type)
where name in ('A', 'B')
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]